# Displaying data from Microsoft SQL Server with jetpack compose

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to display data from a remote SQL server in my application. The data im fetching is a URL for an image, that i will display with asynchronous image.
So far i've established a connection, can load the data and print it. Every time I try to display any of it in my UI my app crashes.
Can anyone point me in the right direction of what i need to research, and what this problem could be called? Then i can research it myself. I have established the connection with jdbc.
Can the data maybe be fetched with a network connection even when it is on a SQL database?

Im not really expecting code answers. i would just like to know which direction i could take to solve this.
I tried multiple things and have researched a lot, but everything seems to be with a network connection and with HTTp calls. could i also use this?
Otherwise it is RMOm and SQLite can i connect my remote database to this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1、First, the App is the interface API for accessing the web server, and then the web server, such as springCloud or Java Servlet, connects to the database SQL Server through JDBC.

2、After the web server connects to the database through JDBC, it can query the data content in the database through SQL statements.

3、Generally, if a picture is stored in SQL Server, it is mapped to the disk address of the server, but if you want to store the picture in the database, it needs to be stored in blob format, and then the data format returned by the web server query must ensure that the App can read it.